# Developing with self-owned python pip dependencies and docker

Tags: python, docker, pip, setuptools, pipenv

I have several python apps (each in separate GitHub repos) which have grown to the point that they all need access to some functions and classes that live inside of one of the apps.

I have extracted the shared code into a separate repo and have it pushed as a package into Gemfury.

I am now stuck on the steps required to make development with this package easy - the package is installed as a dependency via a Pipfile and everything loads into my development docker container as expected.

However, if I want to make changes to this package, it’s a long winded process of pushing a new version, installing the new version just to see how it acts with my main apps code.

I now have a separate checkout of the shared repo loaded into the docker container as a volume, but when using ‘python setup.py develop’ the develop version isn’t user over the previously installed version (as part of the install from Pipfile.lock when the container is created).

Does anybody else have this challenge and know a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

With regular `pip install` you have:

```
src> git checkout ...app1.git
src> git checkout ...app2.git
src> pip install app1
src> pip install app2
```

this installs using versions fetched from `install_requires` in `setup.py` (in global scope). If your order is incorrect it will fetch the app from pypi rather than use your local version.

I don't know about pipenv, but with virtualenv you can keep your code and environment separate:

```
src> virtualenv dev
src> . dev\bin\activate
(dev) src> pip install -r app1\requirements.txt
(dev) src> pip install -r app2\requirements.txt
(dev) src> pip install -e app1
(dev) src> pip install -e app2
```

then any changes to app1 will be immediately visible to app2 provided that app2's requirements.txt includes `-e ../app1`. (Removing the `-e ../` when running a ci pipeline can be done with `sed 's,-e ../,,g' requirements.txt > requirements-ci.txt`, and it will then pick the latest version published to Gemfury).

Your virtualenv is insulated from any globally installed packages.